# Invalid results in jqgrid when filtering a range of numeric value

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

We're having some issues with filtering in jqGrid. We've built some dynamic filters for the categories that we list on the site, the filters are constructed from the backend where you select the property to filter on and then which type of filter it should be rendered as i.e. toggle or slider.

If a category contain items that, with a specified property, have a range from < 100 to > 100 then everything works as expected when both slider handles are on the same "side" of the 100 value. If the lower handle is less than 100 and the upper is above then the results are incorrect. Here are a few screenshots to show what is happening:

Default filter with min and max values set, no filter rule is applied as you see on the second image.

[image: Default empty filter]

[image: The empty filter array]

If we then move the upper handle one step to the left the whole result set goes away, and as you can see the rule array now contain a "le" rule with 178 as data, this should show all the results except the largest one.

[image: Filter with upper handle moved one step]

[image: One "le" filter has been added to the array]

If we keep pulling the upper handle to the left the filtering and the results will work as expected when it reaches a value of 100. Between the values 49 and 99 everything is ok but as soon as the handles are on both sides of the 100 value, the result is incorrect.

[image: Upper handle moved to be < 100, then everything works again]

[image: Same filter only the value is less than 100]

If I have a dynamic filter which has values that range from > 100 to > 500 then it works but as soon as a single value falls under 100 then it stops working correctly.

We're having a hard time getting our heads around this one to say the least and would appreciate anything that could shine some light on this :)